# sqoop import-all-tables : not working

Tags: sqoop

- CDH version = 5.5.0-0
- Hive process is up & running - No issues

I try to import tables from MySQL into hive using the below script.Tables not importing into Hive.Can you please help me what is the issue or am I missing something?

```
sqoop import-all-tables \
 --num-mappers 1 \
 --connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db" \
 --username=reatil_dba \
 --password=cloudera \
 --hive-import \
 --hive-overwrite \
 --create-hive-table \
 --compress \
 --compresession-codec org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec \
 --outdir java_files
```

ERROR:

```
Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
16/10/12 06:36:21 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6-cdh5.5.0
16/10/12 06:36:21 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
16/10/12 06:36:21 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for import-all-tables:
16/10/12 06:36:21 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --compresession-codec
16/10/12 06:36:21 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec
16/10/12 06:36:21 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --outdir
16/10/12 06:36:21 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: java_files
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo, argument name  should be  `--compression-codec` instead of `--compresession-codec`